# style.css not loading in wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles

Here is my code that is not working in wordpress theme. using this code trying to getting style.css file from wp root folder. what's problem in this code is any thing not correct like function name

```
<?php
function add_style() { wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri()); }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_style');
?>
```

But this code in wp function file is working correctly

```
register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => __('Primary Menu')
    )) ;
```

So can any one help me ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

add this to your header.php

Answer (score 1):

```
function custom_scripts_method() {

  /*  CSS  */
  wp_enqueue_style( 'boostrap-style', get_template_directory_uri().'path to file from theme folder' ); 

}       

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts_method' );

?>
```

add this in the functions.php file

and remember to use the : `<?php wp_head(); ?>`
in the head of your html

Comment: Please don't post only some code as an answer. It's better to also explain what's wrong and how your code fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander I solve my problem I am trying to apply css on index.php without using wp_Head() thanks